# How to make my go daddy based domain name have https url?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https, aws-certificate-manager

I have bought a domain name through go daddy, and I am hosting a website through an ec2 server. I associated the ip address of the ec2 instance with go daddy domain name. At present, the website has an HTTP protocol. I wanted to use HTTPS for the website. I have an elastic ip for the ec2 server, and I am don't want to involve any load balancer. My understanding is that we need ssl certificate to make the website accessible through https.

If we buy the free ssl certificate through aws certificate manager and associate that with domain name in go daddy (by adding aws provided cname), can I access my website through https protocol?, or it's not simple as I am understanding? Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> If we buy the free ssl certificate through aws certificate manager and
>   associate that with domain name in go daddy (by adding aws provided
>   cname)

That's not possible. You don't get a CNAME with an SSL certificate. The free SSL certificates provided by AWS Certificate Manager can only be used with load blancers, API Gateway or CloudFront distributions. You can't use one directly with an EC2 server.

You will need to install an SSL certificate in the web server software that is running on the EC2 server. If you want a free SSL certificate you will need to look into [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).